# Bash brace expansion in php?

Tags: php, bash

Is there a php way of accomplishing bash brace expansion? For example

```
[chiliNUT@server ~]$ echo {hello,hi,hey}\ {friends,world},
hello friends, hello world, hi friends, hi world, hey friends, hey world,
```

something like

```
<?php
echo brace_expand("{hello,hi,hey} {friends,world}");
//hello friends, hello world, hi friends, hi world, hey friends, hey world,
```

Currently I am using

```
<?php
echo shell_exec("echo {hello,hi,hey}\ {friends,world}");
```

But it does not seem like the correct way to go about it (and probably wouldn't work on a windows server)

**NOTE** that this is just for the use case of printing a string, not any of the other features of brace expansion such as those related to running groups of commands.

Comment: You could use nested loops, no? I don't know of any built-in php functions that does this.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois I thought about nested loops, but it seems like you would have to know the number of brace expressions ahead of time, whereas bash can handle an arbitrary number of brace expressions

Comment: Is it just about printing a text?

Comment: @MoeinPorkamel for my use case, yes, absolutely, just printing a string

Comment: If it's acceptable from the performance perspective, use `shell_exec()` as you are doing. If this is a task you would like to perform in a loop you might start a shell using [`popen`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php) and reuse the open shell for every expansion you want to perform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the job in your case ( and you can improve it ):

```
<?php

function brace_expand($string)
{
    preg_match_all("/\{(.*?)(\})/", $string, $Matches);

    if (!isset($Matches[1]) || !isset($Matches[1][0]) || !isset($Matches[1][1])) {
        return false;
    }

    $LeftSide = explode(',', $Matches[1][0]);
    $RightSide = explode(',', $Matches[1][1]);

    foreach ($LeftSide as $Left) {
        foreach ($RightSide as $Right) {
            printf("%s %s" . PHP_EOL, $Left, $Right);
        }
    }
}

brace_expand("{hello,hi,hey} {friends,world}");
```

Output:

```
hello friends
hello world
hi friends
hi world
hey friends
hey world
```

---

Edit: unlimited brace support

```
<?php

function brace_expand($string)
{
    preg_match_all("/\{(.*?)(\})/", $string, $Matches);

    $Arrays = [];

    foreach ($Matches[1] as $Match) {
        $Arrays[] = explode(',', $Match);
    }

    return product($Arrays);
}

function product($a)
{
    $result = array(array());
    foreach ($a as $list) {
        $_tmp = array();
        foreach ($result as $result_item) {
            foreach ($list as $list_item) {
                $_tmp[] = array_merge($result_item, array($list_item));
            }
        }
        $result = $_tmp;
    }
    return $result;
}

print_r(brace_expand("{hello,hi,hey} {friends,world} {me, you, we} {lorem, ipsum, dorem}"));
```

Comment: this will handle exactly 2 braced expressions, but not an arbitrary number of them

Comment: this is awesome! it doesn't account for characters between the braces though (ie,  `{hello,hi} to my {friends,enemies}` should yield `hello to my friends hello to my enemies hi to my friends hi to my enemies` but I think I can figure that out on my own; this is a fantastic start.